# Uml-Designer: add java.net.URL property to class

Tags: uml-designer

it is very nice tool. I have installed it very quickly and simple in STS.

The Question.
In a class diagram  i would like to compliment my class with some "Parameter" of java defined Type. For example java.net.URL / URI.
In properties editor i see only `<<EDataType>> <Primitive Type> String` and can't change it or select some other one frome `java.net`

How can i achieve it ?
Or please provide me the reference where i can read about it.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

UML Designer provides by default few Java primitive types : [image: Default Java types in UML Designer]

If you need other types you have to create them thanks to the Data Type or the Primitive Type tools available in the Class diagram palette.

Then if you need to share those types between different projects, you can create a Profile which contains only the types and then use this profile from your other projects.

If you create a such profile do not hesitate to contribute a pull request to UML Designer in order that I can integrate it : http://www.umldesigner.org/developer-guide/contribute.html